# UIcollectionview within UITableviewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` within a `UITableviewCell` that displays Images. All the images are displayed just fine. I want to set it up so that when you tap an image cell it performs a segue which displays the image on a `UIViewController`. In my prepare for segue method, the index of the image cell is not being set. only the very first cell(index 0) is passed despite clicking on a different image cell. Did some research but all I found was this link..

http://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell

it helped me understand that the problem was making sure that the `UICollectionView` understands that the `UIViewController` is its delegate and not the `UITableViewCell` but tha'ts about all I got from it..not sure how to go about it. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showPhoto"])
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems] lastObject];

        if([segue.destinationViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(setImage:)])
        {
            _currentItem =[_photoItems objectAtIndex:indexPath];

            [segue.destinationViewController performSelector:@selector(setImage:) withObject:_currentItem];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use collectonview inside tableview.Collectionview is enough i think

Comment: Hey Lithu, its because on the 1st cell I am displaying information about the album. The whole view does not contain only a collection view. So the 1st cell displays information about the album and the second cell contains the collection view which displays the photos in the album, thats why..